# Spring boot and Thymeleaf application: jquery is loading but not executing

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

I have created a simple spring boot application for my View is loading jquery but not executing it.Details are below:
**My Project structure**

[[image: [1]]

**My Controller**

[image]

**My JqueryCode**

[image]

**My HTML page that import jQuery**
[image]

Chrome Inspector shows jquery is loaded fine

[image]

But still my jQuery code is not running, and if I try running it directly from console., is says **jQuery is not Defined**

Guys please tell me what am i doing wrong / or missing.

Comment: Could you post the generated HTML? Also, does this occur on other browsers? It looks like the JS resources all loaded fine, so is there anything in materialize.js that may be delaying the document from becoming ready and hence the exeution of the $(document).ready()?

Comment: @FinbarrO'Brien generated HTML? do you want html page source

Comment: @FinbarrO'Brien I also checked by removing materialize.js.
Still same problem?
Even if i don't import jquery lib and import my jquery code, it doesn't say    $/jQuery not defined. 
It simply doesn't execute any js file or library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the:

```
<script type="javascript"
```

to

```
<script type="application/javascript"
```

it should work, type='javascript' is not a defined media type according to http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

Comment: Thanks you so much,
Can't believe i missed this.
You saved my day\